# Do I need to use a pointer in this case?

Tags: c++, class

```
class Cat{
           private:
           float weight;
           int age;
           public:
           float getweight();
           bool compareweight(Cat*);
};
Cat::getweight(){
return weight;
}
bool Cat::compareweight(Cat* other){
return weight > other->weight;
}
```

Do I need to use a Cat pointer in the function compareweight or can I use a stack object?

Comment: No, imo the most appropiate signature would be `bool Cat::compareWeight(const Cat& other)` , and `bool Cat::compareWeight(Cat cat)` is fine too, since the type is simple.

Comment: Also, you're comparing the weight with itself right now. It should be `weight > other->weight`, or without the pointer `weight > other.weight`

Comment: @George: Why are you answering in the comment section?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm on my phone :)

Comment: @George: That is not a good reason to post in the wrong place, thanks

Comment: Why did I get so many downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question is pretty brief. You don't explain why you think you might need to use a pointer, or how the function is to be used, or what's to be passed into it, or what a cat is. And the way to define a comparison function is fairly well documented both online and in your C++ textbook. Also you appear to have a misconception about "stack objects" - an expression of non-pointer type need not relate to "stack objects" so again this is an indication that perhaps more research was required.

Comment: @BasilHallaq not down voter; but in addition to the above comment, you say "in this case" but you don't make it clear why you think this case would be different than any other.  (not that it makes any difference to the answer)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to pass objects around is by const reference if you're not changing them.  This will avoid copying (like passing a pointer) but ensure that you have an item as well as not allow you to modify the object.

```
bool Cat::compareWeight(const Cat& other)
```

is what you'd use ideally.

The next best alternative would be a pointer to a const object

```
bool Cat::compareWeight(Cat const* other)
```

But this is more likely to have issues with invalid objects getting passed in; and thus not preferred.

Comment: It would also effectively prevent comparing with a temporary, which is just annoying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a temporary - that you can change ... if you ever wanted to hide your intent; copy seems to be the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
bool Cat::compareweight(Cat other)
```

you get a mostly unwanted copy of your Cat object.
So you should use a pointer or a reference.

```
bool Cat::compareweight(const Cat& other) const
{ return other.weight > weight ; }

bool Cat::compareweight(const Cat* other) const
{ return other->weight > weight; }
```

In addition:
You should declare the methods as const, because the methods did not change the contents of the object and you also can make the pointer and the reference be const, as they also did not change the objects corresponding to them. If you do not so, you can't use your methods with const objects of them!

Comment: "Unwanted copy" that copy most likely improves performance if the compare isn't inlined.

Comment: Please note that OP's compare is the opposite.

Comment: @PasserBy "if the compare isn't inlined" -> "if the compare is inlined" ?

Comment: @user463035818 If it's inlined everything probably gets optimized away. Otherwise you'd get an indirection on the reference.